# Duplicated Time Series are shown using D3-timeseries() in javascript but it is expected to show only one plot

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am currently using the code repository D3-timeseries at https://github.com/mcaule/d3-timeseries

The problem is that I only want to draw one time series but the plot I get is [image]

From the scroll bar of the attached picture, you can see that it creates tons of the same time series plot.

Below you can see my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<style>
.dot {
  stroke: #000;
}
</style>
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="max-age=0" />
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" /> 
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="0" />
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="Tue, 01 Jan 1980 1:00:00 GMT" />
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />
<body>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script src="d3-timeseries/src/d3_timeseries.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="d3-
timeseries/src/d3_timeseries.css">

<script type="text/javascript">

//var margin = { top: 50, right: 50, bottom: 50, left: 50 };



function main() {
  d3.json("PeriodDetection-result.json", function(error, data) {

    if (error) {
      console.log(error);
      return;
    }

    data.forEach(function(d){ d.newDate = new Date(d.newDate * 1000) 
})

    var chart = d3.timeseries()
              .addSerie(data,{x:'newDate',y:'temp'},
{interpolate:'monotone',color:"#333"})
          .width(1000)

    chart("body")
    var show = true;


  });
}



setInterval(function() { main(); }, 250);

main();

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

My date file looks like [image]

I attach the put a simplified json file below as well, which should be saved as PeriodDetection-result.json.

[{"newDate":519955200,"temp":6.6},{"newDate":520041600,"temp":6},{"newDate":520128000,"temp":6.9},{"newDate":520214400,"temp":7.7},{"newDate":520300800,"temp":8},{"newDate":520387200,"temp":3.9},{"newDate":520473600,"temp":0.8},{"newDate":520560000,"temp":2.8},{"newDate":520646400,"temp":8},{"newDate":520732800,"temp":9.8},{"newDate":520819200,"temp":11.4},{"newDate":520905600,"temp":8.6},{"newDate":520992000,"temp":5.2},{"newDate":521078400,"temp":6.6},{"newDate":521164800,"temp":5.7},{"newDate":521251200,"temp":4.6},{"newDate":521337600,"temp":5.8},{"newDate":521424000,"temp":7},{"newDate":521510400,"temp":4.8},{"newDate":521596800,"temp":4.4},{"newDate":521683200,"temp":4.4},{"newDate":521769600,"temp":7.9},{"newDate":521856000,"temp":10.6},{"newDate":521942400,"temp":5},{"newDate":522028800,"temp":7.6},{"newDate":522115200,"temp":9.2},{"newDate":522201600,"temp":9.7},{"newDate":522288000,"temp":8.8},{"newDate":522374400,"temp":6.8},{"newDate":522460800,"temp":9.4},{"newDate":522547200,"temp":11},{"newDate":522633600,"temp":2.5},{"newDate":522720000,"temp":2.1},{"newDate":522806400,"temp":5.4},{"newDate":522892800,"temp":6.2},{"newDate":522979200,"temp":7.8},{"newDate":523065600,"temp":7.4},{"newDate":523152000,"temp":9.3},{"newDate":523238400,"temp":9.3},{"newDate":523324800,"temp":9.5},{"newDate":523411200,"temp":8.5},{"newDate":523497600,"temp":10},{"newDate":523584000,"temp":7.7},{"newDate":523670400,"temp":9.3},{"newDate":523756800,"temp":9.1},{"newDate":523843200,"temp":3.5},{"newDate":523929600,"temp":3.6},{"newDate":524016000,"temp":2.5},{"newDate":524102400,"temp":1.7},{"newDate":524188800,"temp":2.7},{"newDate":524275200,"temp":2.9},{"newDate":524361600,"temp":5.3},{"newDate":524448000,"temp":7.7},{"newDate":524534400,"temp":9.1},{"newDate":524620800,"temp":9.4},{"newDate":524707200,"temp":7.3},{"newDate":524793600,"temp":8.4},{"newDate":524880000,"temp":9.2},{"newDate":524966400,"temp":6.6},{"newDate":525052800,"temp":9.7},{"newDate":525139200,"temp":12.4},{"newDate":525225600,"temp":10.2},{"newDate":525312000,"temp":5.9},{"newDate":525398400,"temp":7.1},{"newDate":525484800,"temp":7.5},{"newDate":525571200,"temp":9.7},{"newDate":525657600,"temp":12.2},{"newDate":525744000,"temp":5.6},{"newDate":525830400,"temp":5.4},{"newDate":525916800,"temp":8.3},{"newDate":526003200,"temp":10.6},{"newDate":526089600,"temp":9.1},{"newDate":526176000,"temp":11.3},{"newDate":526262400,"temp":10.9},{"newDate":526348800,"temp":8.9},{"newDate":526435200,"temp":6.3},{"newDate":526521600,"temp":9},{"newDate":526608000,"temp":6.1},{"newDate":526694400,"temp":9.1},{"newDate":526780800,"temp":9.6},{"newDate":526867200,"temp":6},{"newDate":526953600,"temp":10},{"newDate":527040000,"temp":11},{"newDate":527126400,"temp":6.2},{"newDate":527212800,"temp":8.3},{"newDate":527299200,"temp":11.3},{"newDate":527385600,"temp":11.3},{"newDate":527472000,"temp":6.7},{"newDate":527558400,"temp":6.6},{"newDate":527644800,"temp":11.4},{"newDate":527731200,"temp":6.9},{"newDate":527817600,"temp":10.6},{"newDate":527904000,"temp":8.6},{"newDate":527990400,"temp":11.3},{"newDate":528076800,"temp":12.5},{"newDate":528163200,"temp":9.9},{"newDate":528249600,"temp":6.9},{"newDate":528336000,"temp":5.5},{"newDate":528422400,"temp":7.8}]

Any help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Stupid error, in the code, just comment out this line,"setInterval(function() { main(); }, 250),then it will work.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Pondjs or Momentjs to do this, its much cleaner, but can be a little tedious. It deals with these points and auto plots them base don how to create the code based on chart implementation chart by using react-timeseries-charts. They both work well together with pond or moment.